# Feature importances, discretization and criterion in decision trees

Tags: classification, decision-tree, feature-selection, entropy, information-theory

I'm working with numerical features and I want to use a Decision Tree classifier in sklearn to find the feature importances.

So, if I select the entropy criterion for splitting, information gain is used as a measure of impurity to split the data. Which I guess, would be equivalent to Fayyad & Irani binary discretization.

In the end, the classifier returns an attribute called "feature importances".

> The feature importances. The higher, the more important the feature.
>   The importance of a feature is computed as the (normalized) total
>   reduction of the criterion brought by that feature. It is also known
>   as the Gini importance [R195].

My question is, even though I'm using information gain to find the best split, does "feature importances" return the value of the Gini importance measured in the split found with the entropy criterion?

Answer (score 0):

Yes! There is an iterative method to calculate Gini importance of different splitting points and as soon as it hits the termination criteria (Minimum Description Length), the optimal splitting points will be returned. You can find more info with a toy example here: http://clear-lines.com/blog/post/Discretizing-a-continuous-variable-using-Entropy.aspx